# Lifetime mismatch when migrating a free function to a trait

Tags: rust, traits

I implemented this small function which returns a reference to a value in a enum. This works fine:

```
pub enum Entry {
    COMMENT,
    NUM(Option<String>, f64),
    STR(Option<String>, String),
    VNUM(Option<String>, Vec<f64>),
    VSTR(Option<String>, Vec<String>),
}

pub fn get_value<'b>(k: &str, entity: &'b [Entry]) -> Option<&'b str> {
    entity
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|x| match x {
            &Entry::STR(ref key, ref v) => if key.as_ref().unwrap().as_str() == k {
                Some(v.as_str())
            } else {
                None
            },
            _ => None,
        })
        .next()
}
fn main() {
    let v = vec![
        Entry::STR(Some("foo".to_string()), "bar".to_string()),
        Entry::NUM(Some("baz".to_string()), 1234f64),
    ];
    let x: Option<&str> = get_value("foo", &v);
}
```

To imbue some polymorphism, I wanted to move this to a trait so that I can call it for different types

```
pub trait GetValue<T> {
    fn get_value<'a>(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str>;
}

impl<'a> GetValue<&'a str> for &'a [Entry] {
    fn get_value(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str> {
        entity
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|x| match x {
                &Entry::STR(ref key, ref v) => if key.as_ref().unwrap().as_str() == k {
                    Some(v.as_str())
                } else {
                    None
                },
                _ => None,
            })
            .next()
    }
}
```

but get the following errors despite not intentionally changing the lifetime specifications. What have I missed?

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     fn get_value(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&str, &'a [Entry]) -> std::option::Option<&'a str>`
              found type `fn(&str, &'a [Entry]) -> std::option::Option<&'a str>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 14:5...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     fn get_value(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 13:1
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<'a> GetValue<&'a str> for &'a [Entry] {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     fn get_value(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&str, &'a [Entry]) -> std::option::Option<&'a str>`
              found type `fn(&str, &'a [Entry]) -> std::option::Option<&'a str>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 13:1...
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<'a> GetValue<&'a str> for &'a [Entry] {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 14:5
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     fn get_value(k: &str, entity: &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'a str> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `PascalCase` for enum variants.

Answer (score 1):

By replacing `&'a [Entry]` and `&'a str` respectively with `Self` and `T` in the signature of your `get_value` method, you get rid of explicit lifetimes in your trait definition. As a consequence, the definition of `GetValue` becomes independent of the types `&'a [Entry]` and `&'a str`, which are specific to your concrete implementation for `&'a [Entry]`. As a side effect your lifetime issue will go away.

```
pub trait GetValue<T> {
    fn get_value(self, k: &str) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<'a> GetValue<&'a str> for &'a [Entry] {
    fn get_value(self, k: &str) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.iter()
            .filter_map(|x| match x {
                &Entry::STR(ref key, ref v) => 
                    if key.as_ref().unwrap().as_str() == k {
                        Some(v.as_str())
                    } else {
                        None
                    },
                _ => None,
            })
            .next()
    }
}
```

This way, `get_value` consumes `self`. In your implementation for `&'a [Entry]` the method `get_value` consumes something of type `&'a [Entry]`. Immutable references are `Copy`, so in this implementation `get_value` actually only consumes a copy (something of type `&'a [Entry]` is still usable after having called `get_value` on it).

`GetValue` could also be implemented for something which is not `Copy`. Calling `get_value` on an instance of such a type would then consume this instance. If you want `get_value` to be more restrictive in this aspect, you can let it take `&'a self` as argument instead of `self`. This requires an explicit lifetime `'a` on your trait:

```
pub trait GetValue<'a, T> {
    fn get_value(&'a self, k: &str) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<'a> GetValue<'a, &'a str> for [Entry] {
    fn get_value(&'a self, k: &str) -> Option<&'a str> { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by thinking about  [trait lifetime subtyping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html)

Defining the trait with a associated lifetime:

```
pub trait GetValue<'c,T> {
    fn get_value<'a : 'c>(&'c self, k : &str, entity : &'a [Entry]) -> Option<T>;
}
```

and then the implementation telling Rust that the return type is dependent on `self` and not `entity`

```
impl<'c> GetValue<'c,&'c str> for &'c [Entry] {
    fn get_value<'a : 'c>(&'c self, k : &str, entity : &'a [Entry]) -> Option<&'c str> {
        entity
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|x| match x {
            &Entry::STR(ref key,ref v) => if key.as_ref().unwrap().as_str() == k { Some(v.as_str()) } else { None },
            _ => None
        })
            .next()
    }
}
```